# scientifically-backed vampire 'powers'

Tags: science-based, vampires

what classic vampire traits and abilities (think super speed, invisibility, shapeshifting) would be possible in a world without magic?

bonus points if you figure out how sunlight damages them, how they live for centuries, and why they are compelled to count things

these vampires being the typical folklore type. drink human blood, injured in the sun, kill their victims, pale etc.

Comment: Superspeed and invisibility are not classic vampire traits. Or, better, what is a "classic" vampire?

Comment: sorry, i just see superspeed and invisibility a lot. and i mean the usual 'undead bloodsucking person, turned by another vampire, nocturnal etc etc etc'. i hope that clears it up, i am quite bad at explaining things

Comment: @L.Dutch: Classical [vampire tap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vampire_tap). Provides a connection to a super-speed (10 Mbit/sec) [10BASE5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/10BASE5) "thick wire" Ethernet cable. The cable is usually shrouded in a cable conduit which may count as a sort of invisibility.

Comment: +1 to AlexP for really stretching definition of "vampire"

Comment: each one of these attributes is a question in itself.  My idea for "sunlight damages" is not the same as my idea for "live for centuries".  Maybe split this up - it is broad as written.

Comment: [This question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/122625/justifying-why-a-trolls-skin-would-turn-to-stone-in-sunlight) might help with the damage in sunlight problem.

Comment: See [this one](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/37122/how-can-a-vampire-have-quick-burst-of-superhuman-speed) for how a vampire could have super speed.

Comment: Hi AzaleaGarden! (Nice name!) Please check out the [help] and the [tour]. They'll help you write focused, single topic questions. Also don't forget to make use of the search box: it's very possible some of your questions have been answered already.

Answer (score 4):

I think you'd be best going for a vampire made of 'utility fog' not unlike overwatch's  reaper.

They can spread out to become invisible or move quickly through self generated air currents, or rearrange themselves to shape shift.

The machines can simply be replicated and added to the vampires fog allowing for immortality, (perhaps self-replicated or replicated by a few thousand mother nanites.)

They are compelled to count things because of a quirk of utility fog psychology or perhaps due to a (computer) virus that infected vampires a while ago.

They are damaged by sunlight because the small components of the nanomachienes are delicate and damaged by differential heating, or perhaps their fine circuitry gets fried by U.V. radiation.

The nanites are made of carbon, which is obtained from human blood as these nanites where first developed for medical purposes and were designed to use the patients blood to self-replicate.

Edit:
Paleness is caused by a coating of titanium dioxide (very very heavy duty sunscreen) used to try and resist the aforementioned UV frying the circuitry. Though is obviously not 100% effective or perhaps is only effective when intact, meaning these vampires are only damaged by sunlight when scratched or when trying to spread out, shapeshift or use any other abilities.